# Как выбрать enum по его имени

Tags: java, enum

Я новичок в java, поэтому постоянно задаю тупые вопросы. Вот один из них.
У меня есть такой enum:

```
public enum Color {
    BLUE("синий"),
    YELLOW("жёлтый"),
    WHITE("белый");
}
```

Мне очень хочется чтобы я мог волшебным образом сделав что-то такое:
`Color color = Color.magicMethod("синий")`
получить переменную `color` содержащую в себе то же самое, что я бы получил, если бы сделал
`Color color = Color.BLUE`
Я нашёл информацию про `.valueof()`, но там в качестве параметра нужно передать "BLUE" вместо "синий"

Признателен за ваше потраченное время и ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public enum Color {
    
    BLUE("синий"),
    YELLOW("жёлтый"),
    WHITE("белый");
    
    private final String colorName;

    private Color(String colorName) {
        this.colorName = colorName;
    }
    
    private final static Map<String, Color> colors = Arrays.stream(Color.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k.colorName, v->v));
    
    public static Color getColorByName(String colorName) {
        return colors.get(colorName);        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Пока не у компа, но выглядит, действительно, как решение. Приду, отвечу

Comment: Действительно помогло, спасибо